# get parent id of a class from a click of the child class

Tags: jquery, html

I have four `<div>` container as shown below:

```
 <div class="parentBox">
  <div class="childBox" id="20">
      <div>some content with in this div</div>
      <div>another div with more sontent</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the childBox id into a jQuery variable when I click anywhere within the childBox div. I've tried the following which gives me `undefined`

```
 $('.parentBox').click(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

also tried this which gave me parent is not a function

```
var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```

and tried this which just gives me a blank in console log

```
var id = event.target.id;
```

Can someone please help?

```js
     $('.parentBox').click(function (event) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        
        //does not work
        console.log($(this).parnet().attr('id'));
        
        //also does not work
        console.log(event.target.id);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentBox">
      <div class="childBox" id="20">
          <div>some content with in this div</div>
          <div>another div with more sontent</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why not add the listener to the `childBox` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `.childBox` id when clicking on `.childBox` div you can just hook the click event on the `.childBox` class:

```
$('.childBox').click(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to access the `.childBox` from `.parentBox` event you can do this:

```
$('.parentBox').click(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).find('.childBox').attr('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

When dynamically adding children it's a good idea to hook the event on the parent or on the document object like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.childBox' , function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: it has to be from the parentBox class as I'm using this code in a Jquery where the childbox are created by the jquery

Comment: yes this worked great thank you will now have to implement this into the bigger project

Comment: Shoot me a question if you have issues because there are several gotchas when dynamically adding elements and jquery event handlers.

Comment: one problem I've found with this. If there are three child boxes each with a different id, e.g (id=21, id=22, id=23) no mater what div I click on i always get 21 the first child box

Comment: that's why it's better to hook the event on the childbox as when it's hooked on the parent one it works only if there's only one childbox child. I can adjust both approaches if you can share the html structure you are working with

Comment: add it to gist.github.com or something similar

Comment: not used this before so sorry if this is wrong. Ive uploaded the code to Git this is the path I believe d914aac

Comment: hm.. can't open it.. if you can't manage with gist, try with http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: added to code pen here will try fiddle   https://codepen.io/brackstone/pen/ZEYzwxY

Comment: Try this:
`$(document).on("click",".eventBox",function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'););
});`

instead of `$('.container').click...`

it will bind the event to the document and will work for every dynamically added eventBox. If you want you can bind it to .parentClass too. [Here's](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-bind-click-event-to-dynamically-added-elements-in-jquery.php) a similar example you can read more about.

Comment: Glad to help ypu!

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work

```
$(".parentBox").on('click', "div.childBox",
     function() {var myId = $(this).attr('id'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```js
$('.parentBox').click(function (event) {
    var id = $($(this).children('div')[0]).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```